# How to dynamically load directive into page

Tags: angularjs

I have an html file with a controller and a directive with a template url. I want to load/compile the directive conditionally in the controller:

### Controller:

```
app.controller('TestController', function TestController($http, $scope, $compile) {

$scope.loadData = function (pageId) {
    var pUrl = <some url>
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: pUrl
    }).success(function (data, status) {
        $scope.pData = data;
        var htm = '<test-directive></test-directive>';
        var elm = angular.element("#id").append(htm);
        $compile(elm)($scope);
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        alert('error');
    });
};

$scope.loadData();

});
```

### Directive:

```
'use strict';

app.directive('testdirective', function ($http) {
var uDirective = {};

uDirective.restrict = 'E';
uDirective.templateUrl = 'js/directives/testdirective.html';
uDirective.controller = function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
$scope.showDirectiveData();

    $scope.showDirectiveData = function () {
        $scope.directiveDataCollection = <get data>;
    };
};

uDirective.compile = function (element, attributes) {
    // do one-time configuration of element.

    var linkFunction = function ($scope, element, atttributes) {
    };

    return linkFunction;
};

return uDirective;
});
```

### Template used in Directive

```
<div>
   <div ng-repeat="directiveData in directiveDataCollection">
      <span><h4>{{directiveData.Title}}</h4></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

How do i get to compile the code in the TestController, load the directive dynamically, and finally load the content and append the content in scope?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a general template for you to reference that abstracts and also demonstrates a few Angular concepts:

**JS**

```
.directive('parentDirective', function(Resource, $compile){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
      Resource.loadData().then(function(result){
        scope.data = result.data;
        var htm = '<child-directive></child-directive>';
        var compiled = $compile(htm)(scope);
        elem.append(compiled);
      });
    }
  }
})
.directive('childDirective', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>Content: {{data.key}}</div>'
  }
})
.factory('Resource', function($http){
  var Resource = {};

  Resource.loadData = function(){
    return $http.get('test.json');
  }

  return Resource;
})
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <parent-directive></parent-directive>
</body>
```

Notice that there is no controller code. This is because *controllers should never manipulate the DOM* - one reason is that it will make your code a PITA to test. So, I put everything in directives, where it should probably be in your case as well.

I also moved the $http service into a factory. Anything state/model related should be in a service. Among other reasons, by doing this, you can inject it almost anywhere (including inside of directives) to access your data without worrying about it disappearing when a controller unloads.

**EDIT**

You should also consider the dissenting view of the dynamic loading approach in general in the accepted answer of [Dynamically adding Angular directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482592/dynamically-adding-angular-directives)

Comment: A small addition: if the child directive has an isolated scope and has no access to _data_ in the parent controller you could simply rewrite the child template like `template: '<div content="data">Content: {{content.key}}</div>'`. Great solution, thank you @marc-kline!

Comment: NOTE: this only works if the child directive explicitly sets the template html.  If you attempt to load a template from a URL using templateURL or $http.get or $templateRequest it will not work.

Comment: @nuander Strange, loading templateUrl worked for me using Angular 1.5